# Spring boot Kotlin pagination without JPA

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, paging

I am building a Spring Boot rest API with Kotlin. I tried to find some information on how to do pagination in Spring Boot, because I want to return only some fixed amount of data at once (and then if requested, next chunk of information).

I was able to find tutorials and code samples where people used JPA and then it seemed to be relatively simple to have an interface that extends PagingAndSortingRepository. This is not possible for me, I'm using jdbc templates in DAO to access my DB. How can paging be done here without using JPA?

There are also interfaces Page and Pageable at my disposal, but can these be used without JPA? And if yes, how?

Comment: If you are using spring jdbc template for querying data from database, you should understand that it is just SQL statements. And if you need some pagination for your queries - just add limit and offset parameters. Your question is very similar with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043701/how-can-i-implement-a-pagination-in-spring-jdbctemplate
Check out link - I hope you will find all necessary information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i implement a pagination in spring jdbcTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043701/how-can-i-implement-a-pagination-in-spring-jdbctemplate)