# Fetch 4-5 million records from Postgres and process them JAVA

Tags: spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am currently using `JdbcTemplate` to fetch the data and then use `ResultSet` to store the data in an `ArrayList`. However, as a result of this, I get the following error - `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`. Is there any way I could fetch and process a few records and then again fetch the other batch of data?

P.S - I am currently using the `jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(fetchSize);`, but it doesn't work. Also, I cannot use pagination. Lastly, have set the `-Xmx` size to 2gb but still doesn't work.

Comment: When stuffing things into a list everything wil be read. So either you have to resort to pagination or, if you are on a recent version of Spring you can use the `stream` methods on `JdbcTemplate` to process the records (don't stuff them in a list!).

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57398082/1237402 . Pagination seems to be possible with JdbcTemplate. The OOM happens because there are db records that can't be fit in the 2GB memory of your application

Comment: You essentially ask for pagination but then you write you can't use pagination. I'm confused. Also if you put all your data in a `List` it won't matter if it arrives in batches or in one big hunk. Could you clarify what you really want to do with the data? Writing it in a `List` certainly isn't the final goal, is it?

Comment: @JensSchauder I have to read all the data in memory and process those data, I don't need pagination since the application doesn't have any UI it's all just backend processing of data. Additionally, I need to modify a few of the columns for each row that I read from the DB

Comment: @M.Deinum do you have any reference code for the same?

Comment: @Malathi I'll try to follow that and update you. Thank you.

Comment: Pagination has nothing to do with UI, it has to do with processing in chunks. You simply cannot read those 4 million lines in memory and process them. That simply won't fit. As stated multiple times either use the `stream` methods from the `JdbcTemplate` and process a row without having the need for lots of memory (if you can use a list you can use a stream) or use pagination (read 1000 rows process them then read the next 1000 rows etc).

Comment: @M.Deinum do you have any reference for the pagination logic?

Comment: No as it depends on the database. I was also thinking you could use the `RowCallbackHandler` if you are interested in processing only. That will give you 1 row at a time.

Comment: @M.Deinum would this be able to solve the problem "stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY); stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);"

Comment: no, not as long as you fetch everything into a list. The problem is you are fetching everything, if you don't change that it will simply never work.

Comment: @M.Deinum I need a list to store the data, I can't change that data structure.

Comment: Then it simplky will never work. You cannot store that many rows in memory at once, changing to a cursor, stream etc. will not help if you keep fetching everything as a list. You need to change the design and your processing.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am trying to return the resultSet as a Response of the ResultSetExtractor but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea?

 `ResultSet rs = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(query, params, new ResultSetExtractor<ResultSet>() {
            @Override
            public ResultSet extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                return resultSet;
            }
        });`

Comment: that won't work and still if you retrieve the list it still won't work.