# Springboot + MS Sql Server (Azure Cloud) selecting 100K records failing due to Connection reset

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot

I am using Springboot framework with MyBatis & JDBCTemplate to perform select operation over SQL Server Database.

Following code snippet posting here only JDBCTemplate

```
List<TableName> tnames = new ArrayList<>();
jdbcTemplate.query("select * from testdb.table_name", new RowCallbackHandler() {
    public void processRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            TableName tn = new TableName();
            tn.setStatus(resultSet.getString("status"));
            tnames.add(tn);
            // process it
        }
    }
});
return tnames;
```

**Note:** Code is shortened
Query too having 4-5 tables join , which performs well on SQL server side and fetching almost 100K rows.

But integration with Springboot when I apply `TOP(n)` criteria I found that beyond 47000 rows it wont work and throws following error

```
{"@timestamp":"2022-07-06T04:12:24.161-04:00","message":"InternalServerException Exception : ","loggerSource":"c.m.d.d.a.s.i.r.h.GlobalExceptionHandler","level":"ERROR","stacktrace":"java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(SocketDispatcher.java) sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:54) sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113) sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79) sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50) sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:506)... 10 frames excluded... 114 common frames omittedWrapped by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:353) org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:783)... 7 frames excluded com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2171) com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeFieldName(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:289) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:726) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1514) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1007)... 13 frames excluded javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)... 77 frames excluded java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(SocketDispatcher.java) sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:54) sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113) sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79) sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50) sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:506)... 10 frames excluded... 104 common frames omittedWrapped by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:353) org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:783)... 7 frames excluded com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2171) com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.close(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1214)... 1 frames excluded... 93 common frames omitted","logType":"SERVICE"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-07-06T04:12:24.164-04:00","message":"Found 'Content-Type:application/json' in response","loggerSource":"o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor","level":"DEBUG","logType":"SERVICE"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-07-06T04:12:24.166-04:00","message":"Writing [ErrorApiResponse(code=HTTP500, message=HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error, description=java.io.IOExcep (truncated)...]","loggerSource":"o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor","level":"DEBUG","logType":"SERVICE"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-07-06T04:12:24.167-04:00","message":"Failure in @ExceptionHandler com.dev.infra.rest.handlers.GlobalExceptionHandler#handleInternalException(Exception)","loggerSource":"o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver","level":"WARN","stacktrace":"java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(SocketDispatcher.java) sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:54) sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113) sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79) sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50) sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:506)... 10 frames excluded... 108 common frames omittedWrapped by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:353) org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:783)... 7 frames excluded com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2171) com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1184) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1009)... 16 frames excluded javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)... 77 frames excluded java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)","logType":"SERVICE"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-07-06T04:12:24.168-04:00","message":"Failed to complete request: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer","loggerSource":"o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet","level":"DEBUG","logType":"SERVICE"}
```

Query is executing in 12-17 Seconds

I tried with applying `queryTimeout` wont work.
Any suggestions here would be great !!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What web server are you using? Perhaps you're hitting a max-response-size limit.

Comment: So, I am using embedded tomcat with springboot

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use Pagination than selecting all records at a glance. The connection was kept open long and was terminated by db server. If you eventually have more records this will fail even if you change connection timeout settings. Please visit [how can i implement a pagination in spring jdbcTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043701/how-can-i-implement-a-pagination-in-spring-jdbctemplate) to know how to do Pagination and retrieve all records in batch

Comment: This is for generating JSON response or file export operation. Even though pagination implementation, it would be longer time throughput. sorry to mentioned earlier complete details, that this API is for JSON response / File download direct to client.